# To disable telerik:RadEditor c#

Tags: c#, telerik, radeditor

How to disable the telerik:RadEditor? i gave editor.enabled= false but the control is not visible.

Comment: Control is visible, but renders just contents http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/editmodes/defaultcs.aspx, what do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `editor.enableEditing(false)`

See the telerik forum [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/community-forums/about-telerik/disable-radeditor-using-javascript-on-client-side.aspx).  The question is around disabling the editor from the client-side.  Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in the code-behind you could do

```
editor.EditModes = EditModes.Preview;
```

This will force the editor to be only in Preview mode and not allow the user to change the mode to Design or Html mode. Which disables the toolbar buttons and the edit area is made read only.